# Scheduled tasks / cron on Haiku?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, cron, haiku

It doesn't seem to be called `cron` on Haiku and I don't see anything in Preferences or Applications as of the latest nightly.  (Where) is this functionality in Haiku / what is it called?  (I also searched HaikuDepot for cron, task, sched, and time, with no luck.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that there is an analogue to `cron` available by default on Haiku. There is a [port](http://wiki.poorcoding.com/Haiku.arfonzo.ashx#cron_cronie_BEH_0) of [Cronie](https://fedorahosted.org/cronie/) available for download.

Given the current state of Haiku's multi-user system, it may be tricky to get working with a default install, unless you do this:

```
useradd root
passwd root
```

...and also make the file in `/boot/apps/arfonzo-cronie/var/spool/cron` with your cron settings be called `root`.